# Can the White Court vampires turn humans into new vampires?

Tags: vampire, the-dresden-files

In the Dresden Files series by Jim Butcher there were a few mentions of vampires turning humans into new vampires by the `Red Court` and the `Black Court`, but I can not recall if it can be done by the `White Court` vampires. Can they do it?
Apparently the White Court vamps are near-human creatures which are born like a typical human being.

Comment: note that in Butcher's novels, what humans call "Vampires" are really three unrelated types of creature who all just happen to harbor a demon that feeds on humans ; WC vampires are much more like what we'd call incubi and succubi.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer, *no*. Here's a brief bit of White Court "biology".

A White Court Vampire is distinguished from a human by the demon that lives inside. That demon, often referred to as its Hunger, is the well of energy and skill that the White Court draws from to be supernaturally powerful. I'll paraphrase two sources on where the demon comes from: what Thomas explicitly said, and what we can infer from their characteristics.

First, we know that the White Court is born with their demon in a dormant state, as evidence by Thomas's narration about Inara. When she unknowingly tried to Feed on Harry, it was that dormant demon waking for the first time in her teenage life. Where the new Demons come from is never made clear, but we are told that it grows with its host until their First Feeding, where the demon runs rampant and kills the victim.

This well is fed by emotional energy; lust for the Raiths, fear for the Malvora, and despair for the Skavis, as well as other emotions with the lesser houses. Because everything else acquirable in the Dresdenverse is either personal (e.g. Mantles of power) or generic (such as Red Court Vampirism), so I infer that they can only propagate via reproduction.

Comment: To the anonymous user who suggested an edit to the effect that Lara's offer to Harry meant that someone could become a White Court Vampire; that's not what she meant. 

She meant that Harry should volunteer to be her ally/food, and with that position would come White Court livery.